# Try to make a rpm packet of httpd 2.4.3

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, rpm

my spec file is:

```
%prep
tar zxvf $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/httpd-2.4.3.tar.gz

%build

%install
cd httpd-2.4.3
./configure -prefix=/usr/local/apache
make
make install

%preun
if [ -z "`ps aux|grep httpd | grep -v grep`" ];then
   pkill httpd >/dev/null
exit 0
fi

%files
/usr/local/apache

rpmbuild -ba lx.spec
```

, and the RPM packet of httpd-2.4-3.x86_64.rpm is ok.
But when I installed it by

```
rpm -ivh httpd-2.4-3.x86_64.rpm
```

it's not right, and the error message is:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libpcre.so.1()(64bit) is needed by httpd-2.4-3.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your machine is CentOS or RHEL, you need to install the `pcre.x86_64` package.

```
# yum resolvedep "libpcre.so.0()(64bit)"
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, product-id, rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
0:pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64
```